# Complex updating rule in 'for' loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to write the following 'while' loop:

```
int x = N-1, y = 0;

while ( y < M ) {

    /* Some work */

    if ( x > 0 )
        x--;
    else 
        y++;

}
```

as a 'for' loop. This was my **failed** attempt:

```
for ( int x = N-1, y = 0 ; y < M ; ((x>0)?x--:y++) ) {
    /* Some work */
}
```

This fails to compile since, as the compiler says, the update rule is not a statement.

Do you see any way to naturally write the 'while' loop above as a 'for' loop?

Comment: Why can't you just leave it as a while loop?

Comment: `for ( int x = N-1, y = 0 ; y < M ; ((x>0)?x--:y++) ) {` it would be ununderstandable

Comment: @Daniel, One reason for that is to keep variable localized in the body of loop.

Comment: @Daniel, it's because the 'for' loop has a place reserved for the updating rule. So, when you read it, you expect to find that functionality there.

Comment: @Nikolay, I agree, but that's one of the reasons to ask.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To combine the conditions.

```
 for(int x = N-1, y = 0; y < M ; y += (x > 0)?0:1, x += (x > 0)?-1:0)
```

I suspect this should really be two loops calling a common method.

```
 for(int x = N - 1; x >= 0; x--)
     someMethod(x, 0);
 for(int y = 0; y < M; y++)
     someMethod(0, y);
```

Comment: Technically correct, but please never put this in code. It's so horrifically unreadable.

Comment: But it does seem to answer the implied question of how to write the while loop in a for loop using only 3 parameters of the for loop.

Comment: @Scott, For sure it does, but chnacess of making mistake there is big. Even Peter writing this has made a error. with -= -1. Is valid but, problematic.

Comment: agreed, its not pretty, and I would not recommend.

Comment: @Scott Using two loops is more natural I think.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I actually think the other solution is a better coding style because both x and y variables live within the same scope, the two loop solution, is as easy to read as the other solution, but separates x and y into their own local scopes. That being said, I still voted for this as answering the question best.

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Code should be simple. Just like [Brian Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan) [described it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103299/help-me-understand-this-brian-kernighan-quote) once. So +1 for two for loops.

Comment: Answers like these showing up on Google must be why I see horrible practices in production code.  Haha.  +1 for the true answer to OP's question, though.

Comment: In fact, I was doing the two loops solution before asking the question here in SO, but I didn't want to write a method for just two lines of work, nor I wanted to violate DRY. This is OK for TopCoder rounds anyway. Thanks!!!

Comment: I tested this in my code and it compiles. However, I needed to modify it a bit to make it do the correct thing. I inverted the order of the update rule to get `y += (x>0)?1:0, x+= (x>0)?-1:0`, in order to avoid the side effect of the update of x on the update of y.

Comment: There's a saying along the lines of: "debugging is twice as hard as coding. If you make your code as clever as you can, you'll never be able to debug it."

Comment: @EdwardFalk esp. if you put it all on one line.

Answer (score 14):

You can always leave the update rule empty

```
for ( int x = N-1, y = 0 ; y < M ; ) {

 if ( x > 0 )
        x--;
    else 
        y++;

}
```

Comment: I would ask, at this point, is this actually clearer than the `while` loop?

Comment: It's not really more clear, but the OP doesn't say he wants to make it more clear. He just says he wants a for loop. Mission accomplished, as far as I can see.

Comment: @MarkByers Oh, that wasn't criticism of the answer, just a note.

Comment: In one small point, yes. The x and y are not accessible outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
/* Some work */
```

include the variables x and y? If not, there is an easier way to write the logic of the loop. Currently, your loops counts from N-1 to zero (x) and then from zero to M-1 (y). The entire loop runs (M+N)-1 times.

By combining the initial conditions, you can write:

```
for (int x = 1; x < M+N; x++) {
    /* Some work */
}
```

and do away with the y variable altogether.

If you need to keep the x and y variables as those values, just use a third variable:

```
for (int z = 1; z < M+N; z++) {
    /* Some work */
    (x>0)?x--:y++;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Jack

Comment: Thanks @Jack. You're right in that an unidimensional parameterization can be the good thing to do, depending on the body of the loop.